# jdbc resultSet slow performance

Tags: jdbc, oracle10g

hiii,
     i am calling a stored procedure in a java class in my web application, there are some reports that are taking to much time to render the jsp/HTML ,i have also chercked with stored procedure query its taking only 2 seconds to execute in oracle browser. i have checked my SP calling code where i found that my result set fetch time is very less,but when in trying to iterate result set with While(rst.next) it will almost take 3 mins to print SOP inside the while loop,i doubt there must be issue with ret.next(),
my code is as follows,

```
Connection connection   = null;
CallableStatement stmt  = null;
ResultSet rst           = null ;


connection = DBConnector.getConnection();

stmt = connection.prepareCall("{call MIS_GSGR_ASON.MIS_DIVNETSALE_ASON(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");


            stmt.setString(1,START_DT);                 
            stmt.setString(2,END_DT);                   
            stmt.setString(3,DIVISION);             
            stmt.setString(4,LOC_ID);   
            stmt.setInt(5,USER_GRP);
            stmt.setInt(6,FIELD_ID);
            stmt.setInt(7,Integer.parseInt(PERIOD_ID));
            stmt.setString(8,zone);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(9+INC,OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            stmt.execute();
            rst = (ResultSet) stmt.getObject(9+INC);

            System.out.println("Got resultset . . . .");

            data = new ArrayList<MainActionAll>();


            while(rst.next()){
            System.out.println("In loop");}
```

any help will be highly appriciated,please help me out
thanks ,amol

Comment: I don't know what you'd normally do in your result set iteration, but the simple act of printing to the console in a tight loop is itself *very* expensive

Comment: im just trying to print S.O.P that i have inserted in while loop ,after getting result set only im not able to print that statement,its taking too much time to to get printed on console

Comment: Can you time your code with the output to console commented out?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you run your query via slow network and if there is many rows returned it works very slow?

Add some time checking and instead of printing to console simply count records:

```
...
...
...
stmt.registerOutParameter(9+INC,OracleTypes.CURSOR);
long t0, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5;
t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
stmt.execute();
t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
rst = (ResultSet) stmt.getObject(9+INC);
t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Got resultset . . . .");
data = new ArrayList<MainActionAll>();
t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
t4 = t3;
t5 = t3;

int rec_cnt = 0;
if (rst.next())
    {
    ++rec_cnt;
    t4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (rst.next())
        ++rec_cnt;
    t5 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
System.out.println("execute: " + (t1 - t0));
System.out.println("stmt.getObject: " + (t2 - t1));
System.out.println("Array: " + (t3 - t2));
System.out.println("1st next: " + (t4 - t3));
System.out.println("loop: " + (t5 - t4));
System.out.println("rec cnt: " + (rec_cnt));
```

Try to execute it as near database server as possible to reduce network transfers (localhost preferred). Edit your question with those times.